# Passportjs doesn't populate req.user after successful login

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I'm trying to find out why this simple code doesn't work but I can't figure out. The problem is that after a successful login, req.user is not populated and req.isAuthenticated returns false.

I know that similar question was asked many times but I don't found any solutions.
Thanks.

```
import * as path from 'path'
import * as express from 'express'
import * as session from 'express-session'
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import * as passport from 'passport'
import { BasicStrategy, DigestStrategy } from 'passport-http'
import checkAuthentication from './db'

const app: express.Application = express()

// Configure session store (memory)
app.use(session({
    store: undefined,
    secret: 'stackoverflow_please_help!',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true
    }
}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// This should fill the req.user
passport.serializeUser((user: string, done: express.NextFunction): express.NextFunction => {
    console.log(`[serializeUser] user:`, user)
    return done(null, user)
})

// Should retrive serialized data (user)
passport.deserializeUser((user: string, done: express.NextFunction): express.NextFunction => {
    console.log(`[deserializeUser] user:`, user)
    return done(null, user)
})

// Check if username and password from user are correct
passport.use(
    new BasicStrategy(async (username: string, password: string, done: express.NextFunction ): express.NextFunction => {
        let userValidated
        try {
            userValidated = await checkAuthentication(username, password)
        } catch {
            console.error(`Something wrong calling db.`)
            return done(`Something wrong calling db.`)
        }
        if (userValidated) {
            console.log(`[BasicStrategy] "${username}" login succesfull`)
            return done(null, username)
        } else {
            console.log(`[BasicStrategy] "${username}" login failed`)
            return done(null, false)
        }
}))

const routePages: express.Router = express.Router()

// Authenticate user with BasicStrategy, set session, call req.login, redirect if success or failure
routePages.post('/auth', 
    passport.authenticate('basic', 
    {
        successRedirect: '/secure/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/login.html'
    })
)

// Protected page
routePages.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req: express.Request, res: express.response) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.status(200).send('<h1>Works!</h1>')
})

// Add routes path
const staticFilePath: string = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'www')
app.use('/', express.static(staticFilePath))
app.use('/secure', routePages)

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req: express.Request, res: express.response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    console.log(`[isLoggedIn] authenticated? :`, req.isAuthenticated())
    console.log(`[isLoggedIn] req.sessionID:`, req.sessionID)
    console.log(`[isLoggedIn] req.user:`, req.user)
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if not authenticated, redirect them to the home page
    return res.redirect('/login.html');
}

const listeningPort = 3333
app.listen(listeningPort)
console.log(`Listening to ${listeningPort}`)
```

The console.log I got is:

```
Listening to 3333
[BasicStrategy] "admin" login succesfull
[serializeUser] user: admin
[isLoggedIn] authenticated? : false
[isLoggedIn] req.sessionID: XtPFNEMLbAKxWRRXHwxHKnhTamloicaj
[isLoggedIn] req.user: undefined
```

Software version:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^7.0.60",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "express-session": "^1.15.6",
  "passport": "^0.4.0",
  "passport-http": "^0.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I use secure cookie **but** the connection is not in SSL.
I'm sorry